# CUSTOM HOOK : Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem when calling a custom hook in react.
I have this error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

The custom Hook looks like :

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useMooves(index) {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([1,2,3,4]);
    if (index <= 5) {
      array[index] += 1;
      setArray([...array]);
      continue;
    }
    if (index > 5) {
      array[index] -= 1;
      setArray([...array]);
    }
  return [array]
}

export default useMooves
```

How I call the custom Hook :

```
import useMooves from "../utils/mooves";

function Container() {
  const [array]= useMooves; // THIS IS NOT WORKING : I CAN'T GET THE ARRAY

  return (
    <ul>
      {Array &&
        Array.map((number, index) => {
          return (
            <Circle
              key={index}
              clickHandler={() => useMooves(index)} // THIS IS NOT WORKING CAUSING THE ERROR ABOVE
              index={index}
            />
          );
        })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default Container;
```

The Circle component for info just get the index of li that was clicked :

```
function Circle({  clickHandler, index }) {   return (     <li onClick={() => clickHandler(index)}     >       {index}     </li>   ); }  export default Circle;
```

What I would like is:

1- be able to retrieve the array from the custom hook in the component that calls it.

2- be able to use the custom hooks useMooves ( ) to send it an index by which we retrieve the new array value (back to point 1) when we click on the Circle component.

Everything working fine before I refactored the code and got this error.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `clickHandler={() => useMooves(index)}` - I don't get this line. What is supposed to happen here?

Comment: @mbojko
just to know which index was clicked:
`function Circle({  clickHandler, index }) {
  return (
    <li onClick={() => clickHandler(index)}
    >
      {index}
    </li>
  );
}

export default Circle;`

Comment: Probably your hook needs to return some callback as well as array, and you need to call this callback in the click handler (instead of calling the hook itself, which is a pattern I've never seen before). But the parts you left out "for simplicity" forces us to make uninformed guesses.

Comment: @mbojko
Thanks for your answers.
I've just modified the code to be more explicit. Let's hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. One tangent thing: I have no idea what to make of the use of the index. `if (index < 5)`? But it's an index in the array initialized as 4 elems long, and the size doesn't change, just value of the elements are modified? So `index` will always be `< 5` anyway?

Assuming you know how to figure it out, sth like this should serve your purpose:

```
function useMooves(index) {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([1,2,3,4]);
  
  const handleChange = (index) => /*
     do stuff here; do some modifications of the array, call `setArray` at the end
*/

return [array, handleChange];
}
```

```
function Container() {
  const [array, handleChange] = useMooves();

  return (
    <ul>
      {array &&
        array.map((number, index) => {
          return (
            <Circle
              key={index}
              clickHandler={() => handleChange(index)}
              index={index}
            />
          );
        })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Well it works like a charme.
(I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but my feedback has been recorded)
Thanks again !